# Turn off auto add in Eclipse subversion plugin (Subeclipse) on commit

Tags: php, eclipse, svn

I'm trying to use Eclipse plugin for subversion Subeclipse. When I go to commit code it preselect EVERY file in the project for me. It doesn't make sense as meny files are auto generated by my application and I don't want to commit them. Unchanging everything manually every time I want to commit is a pain.

Do you know how to turn off this feature? I don't want it to make any selection on files I didn't 'svn add'

Comment: learn about svn and `svn:ingore`, google should help you.

Comment: I don't want to be explicit about ignoring. When I use command line I don't have to do that. Created files are not automatically added. I need to svn add them first. Subeclipse doesn't follow this logic.

Comment: Sure because it wants to assist you. Check for configuration, you might be able to control that feature.

Comment: I've already checked the configuration. I also goggled for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you select: **"RightClick on Project->Team->Commit"**, of course this will "check" all files in the project...

What you can do is to manually select the files folders in your source tree, that you want to commit,with **"Shift + LeftClick"** and then do **"RightClick on Selection->Team->Commit"**. Now you will find that only the files that were in the selection or in any folders that were selected are "checked" in the list displayed by Subclipse.

The other way is to `svn:ignore` - this is the **right thing to do** for the "many files auto-generated by your application".

Comment: This might be a semi solution. I don't think I can get more then that from it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is just how it works. When you select a directory it will add all files and directories under it recursively! It is the same a running `svn co /directory` - this will also add all files/folders under the directory recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the "Show unversioned files" box before validating your commit